# django-breadcrumbs flatpages

Tags: django, breadcrumbs, django-flatpages

I following this tutorials: https://github.com/chronossc/django-breadcrumbs/blob/master/README.markdown#3---enable-flatpages--breadcrumbs

Like this, my settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'breadcrumbs.middleware.BreadcrumbsMiddleware',
    'breadcrumbs.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    ...
    'breadcrumbs',
)
```

and my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^services/(?P<url>.*)$', 'breadcrumbs.views.flatpage'),
    ...

)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
    )
```

So,

If I delete my middlewareclass, the flatpages doesn't work. But if i delete my services urls, the flatpages work again. He doesn't use this. I need to know the reason for make a correctly system work.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that 'breadcrumbs.views.flatpage' not found for some reason. Let's import it explicitly.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from breadcrumbs.views import flatpage

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^services/(?P<url>.*)$', flatpage),
    ...

)
```